# Conditional Formatting Row based on

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I like to use Google Sheets to keep my list of stories that I'm working on organized
[like in this photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwmrN.png):

Each row is highlighted a certain color depending on the value of the cell in "B" Column. "Published" is green, "WIP" is orange, [where for range A2:B2, =B2="Published"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xx6t.png)

But at the moment I have to create the conditional formatting formula (CF) for each row one by one. I have to make the CF for Row 2, then copy the CF to Row 3 and edit the formula to replace every B2 with a B3 so it works independently on the next row.

This seems far too tedious to do practically so I was wondering if there was a formula that would allow each row to be formatted individually with one formula? Something where the formula knows to look at B2 in Row 2 to apply the formatting, B3 in Row 3, and so on.

The current formula I'm using is [=B3="Published"] to change the formatting style to a green highlight. But if I do this on all of my cells, it will change all of rows based on the value of B2. Even though in B3 it might be "WIP" instead, which defeats the purpose of highlight. I was hoping it would function like [if: =BX="Published"/ then: apply conditional formatting to Row X]

I'm really sorry about the poor phrasing of this question, I have basically zero knowledge on Google Sheets and don't know how to phrase the question for Google or any other search engine

Comment: Change your apply range and make it `$A2:$F`.

Answer (score 0):

set your range to A2:F and use this set of formulae:

orange

```
=$B2="WIP"
```

blue

```
=$B2="Outline"
```

green

```
=$B2="Published"
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! It says I don't have enough "reputation" to upvote this but it worked like a charm! Thank you so much haha!

Comment: @ModestPal as a new user with a low reputation, you have an option to accept the answer by marking it with a green check mark (if the answer solved your issues of course) - by doing this your reputation will slightly "grow"